# Python how to find any or all strings-list in a line and then print the exact string found

Tags: python

I'm Python beginner, and not too good with dictionaries and lists.

I'm trying to look for certain strings inside a line, and if string is found, print that particular string.

this is the line:

```
{  
  "success": true,
  "start": 0,
  "pagesize": 5,
  "total_count": 4,
  "results_html": "\t<div class=\"market_listing_table_header\">\r\n\t\t<div class=\"market_listing_right_cell market_listing_their_price market_sortable_column\" data-sorttype=\"price\">PRICE<span class=\"market_sort_arrow\" style=\"display:none;\"><\/span><\/div>\r\n\t\t<div class=\"market_listing_right_cell market_listing_num_listings market_sortable_column\" data-sorttype=\"quantity\">QUANTITY<span class=\"market_sort_arrow\" style=\"display:none;\"><\/span><\/div>\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"market_sortable_column\" data-sorttype=\"name\"><span class=\"market_listing_header_namespacer\"><\/span>NAME<span class=\"market_sort_arrow\" style=\"display:none;\"><\/span><\/div>\r\n\t<\/div>\r\n\r\n<a class=\"market_listing_row_link\" href=\"http:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/market\/listings\/730\/%E2%98%85%20Karambit%20%7C%20Stained%20%28Factory%20New%29\" id=\"resultlink_0\">\r\n\t<div class=\"market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row market_listing_searchresult\" id=\"result_0\">\r\n\t\t\t\t<img id=\"result_0_image\" src=\"http:\/\/steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net\/economy\/image\/fWFc82js0fmoRAP-qOIPu5THSWqfSmTELLqcUywGkijVjZYMUrsm1j-9xgEObwgfEh_nvjlWhNzZCveCDfIBj98xqodQ2CZknz5wOuqzNQhscxbDDKJXSMo75TfqBjUx7cNcWN6x_69IfAjn4oPHZbgkY4wdFpTXDqKEbwj4uB89g_VcKMCKoSO73yW4PG5fDw2rpDzIPE231Q\/62fx62f\" style=\"border-color: #8650AC;\" class=\"market_listing_item_img\" alt=\"\" \/>\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"market_listing_right_cell market_listing_their_price\">\r\n\t\t\t<span class=\"market_table_value\">\r\n\t\t\t\tStarting at:<br\/>\r\n\t\t\t\t<span style=\"color:white\">CDN&#36; 396.91<\/span>\r\n\t\t\t<\/span>\r\n\t\t\t<span class=\"market_arrow_down\" style=\"display: none\"><\/span>\r\n\t\t\t<span class=\"market_arrow_up\" style=\"display: none\"><\/span>\r\n\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t\t<div class=\"market_listing_right_cell market_listing_num_listings\">\r\n\t\t\t<span class=\"market_table_value\">\r\n\t\t\t\t<span class=\"market_listing_num_listings_qty\">2<\/span>\r\n\t\t\t<\/span>\r\n\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"market_listing_item_name_block\">\r\n\t\t\t<span id=\"result_0_name\" class=\"market_listing_item_name\" style=\"color: #8650AC;\">\u2605 Karambit | Stained (Factory New)<\/span>\r\n\t\t\t<br\/>\r\n\t\t\t<span class=\"market_listing_game_name\">Counter-Strike: Global Offensive<\/span>\r\n\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t<\/div>\r\n<\/a>\r\n\r\n<a class=\"market_listing_row_link\" href=\"http:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/market\/listings\/730\/%E2%98%85%20Karambit%20%7C%20Forest%20DDPAT%20%28Factory%20New%29\" id=\"resultlink_1\">\r\n\t<div class=\"market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row market_listing_searchresult\" id=\"result_1\">\r\n\t\t\t\t<img id=\"result_1_image\" src=\"http:\/\/steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net\/economy\/image\/fWFc82js0fmoRAP-qOIPu5THSWqfSmTELLqcUywGkijVjZYMUrsm1j-9xgEObwgfEh_nvjlWhNzZCveCDfIBj98xqodQ2CZknz5wOuqzNQhscxbDDKJXSMoy7TfoDTcz_PhvXdC-4_VSKlns4IKSNrkrYdlIF8GGDPLVMlr0vxhriPJcKJSOpCK72STrMm0IRVO1rYe8SeMm\/62fx62f\" style=\"border-color: #8650AC;\" class=\"market_listing_item_img\" alt=\"\" \/>\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"market_listing_right_cell market_listing_their_price\">\r\n\t\t\t<span class=\"market_table_value\">\r\n\t\t\t\tStarting at:<br\/>\r\n\t\t\t\t<span style=\"color:white\">CDN&#36; 383.20<\/span>\r\n\t\t\t<\/span>\r\n\t\t\t<span class=\"market_arrow_down\" style=\"display: none\"><\/span>\r\n\t\t\t<span class=\"market_arrow_up\" style=\"display: none\"><\/span>\r\n\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t\t<div class=\"market_listing_right_cell market_listing_num_listings\">\r\n\t\t\t<span class=\"market_table_value\">\r\n\t\t\t\t<span class=\"market_listing_num_listings_qty\">1<\/span>\r\n\t\t\t<\/span>\r\n\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"market_listing_item_name_block\">\r\n\t\t\t<span id=\"result_1_name\" class=\"market_listing_item_name\" style=\"color: #8650AC;\">\u2605 Karambit | Forest DDPAT (Factory New)<\/span>\r\n\t\t\t<br\/>\r\n\t\t\t<span class=\"market_listing_game_name\">Counter-Strike: Global Offensive<\/span>\r\n\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t<\/div>\r\n<\/a>\r\n\r\n<a class=\"market_listing_row_link\" href=\"http:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/market\/listings\/730\/%E2%98%85%20Karambit%20%7C%20Safari%20Mesh%20%28Factory%20New%29\" id=\"resultlink_2\">\r\n\t<div class=\"market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row market_listing_searchresult\" id=\"result_2\">\r\n\t\t\t\t<img id=\"result_2_image\" src=\"http:\/\/steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net\/economy\/image\/fWFc82js0fmoRAP-qOIPu5THSWqfSmTELLqcUywGkijVjZYMUrsm1j-9xgEObwgfEh_nvjlWhNzZCveCDfIBj98xqodQ2CZknz5wOuqzNQhscxbDDKJXSMop5DfhDDQ619NiWui6_rwOPRK-ttbCYON6OdFJG5LZX_HVbgj0ux9th6MMLsbb9XvojnzpbG5bDxK95Ctaz2tSczny\/62fx62f\" style=\"border-color: #8650AC;\" class=\"market_listing_item_img\" alt=\"\" \/>\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"market_listing_right_cell market_listing_their_price\">\r\n\t\t\t<span class=\"market_table_value\">\r\n\t\t\t\tStarting at:<br\/>\r\n\t\t\t\t<span style=\"color:white\">CDN&#36; 247.19<\/span>\r\n\t\t\t<\/span>\r\n\t\t\t<span class=\"market_arrow_down\" style=\"display: none\"><\/span>\r\n\t\t\t<span class=\"market_arrow_up\" style=\"display: none\"><\/span>\r\n\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t\t<div class=\"market_listing_right_cell market_listing_num_listings\">\r\n\t\t\t<span class=\"market_table_value\">\r\n\t\t\t\t<span class=\"market_listing_num_listings_qty\">2<\/span>\r\n\t\t\t<\/span>\r\n\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"market_listing_item_name_block\">\r\n\t\t\t<span id=\"result_2_name\" class=\"market_listing_item_name\" style=\"color: #8650AC;\">\u2605 Karambit | Safari Mesh (Factory New)<\/span>\r\n\t\t\t<br\/>\r\n\t\t\t<span class=\"market_listing_game_name\">Counter-Strike: Global Offensive<\/span>\r\n\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t<\/div>\r\n<\/a>\r\n\r\n<a class=\"market_listing_row_link\" href=\"http:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/market\/listings\/730\/%E2%98%85%20Karambit%20%7C%20Boreal%20Forest%20%28Factory%20New%29\" id=\"resultlink_3\">\r\n\t<div class=\"market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row market_listing_searchresult\" id=\"result_3\">\r\n\t\t\t\t<img id=\"result_3_image\" src=\"http:\/\/steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net\/economy\/image\/fWFc82js0fmoRAP-qOIPu5THSWqfSmTELLqcUywGkijVjZYMUrsm1j-9xgEObwgfEh_nvjlWhNzZCveCDfIBj98xqodQ2CZknz5wOuqzNQhscxbDDKJXSMoy7TfqBjU3-9NcVtik8roKFlC249qCLbh-ZdFFTcmCX_WEYQz57Eht0_AOL5zdoCLv3ijgazgJXhHtqW9RkOeZ-uw8ko32nUQ\/62fx62f\" style=\"border-color: #8650AC;\" class=\"market_listing_item_img\" alt=\"\" \/>\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"market_listing_right_cell market_listing_their_price\">\r\n\t\t\t<span class=\"market_table_value\">\r\n\t\t\t\tStarting at:<br\/>\r\n\t\t\t\t<span style=\"color:white\">CDN&#36; 504.02<\/span>\r\n\t\t\t<\/span>\r\n\t\t\t<span class=\"market_arrow_down\" style=\"display: none\"><\/span>\r\n\t\t\t<span class=\"market_arrow_up\" style=\"display: none\"><\/span>\r\n\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t\t<div class=\"market_listing_right_cell market_listing_num_listings\">\r\n\t\t\t<span class=\"market_table_value\">\r\n\t\t\t\t<span class=\"market_listing_num_listings_qty\">1<\/span>\r\n\t\t\t<\/span>\r\n\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div class=\"market_listing_item_name_block\">\r\n\t\t\t<span id=\"result_3_name\" class=\"market_listing_item_name\" style=\"color: #8650AC;\">\u2605 Karambit | Boreal Forest (Factory New)<\/span>\r\n\t\t\t<br\/>\r\n\t\t\t<span class=\"market_listing_game_name\">Counter-Strike: Global Offensive<\/span>\r\n\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t<\/div>\r\n<\/a>\r\n"
}
```

And this is my current code
but it doesn't seem to work properly

```
strings = {"%E2%98%85%20Karambit%20%7C%20Safari%20Mesh%20%28Factory%20New%29",
           "%E2%98%85%20Karambit%20%7C%20Boreal%20Forest%20%28Factory%20New%29"}
if any(string in strings for string in line):
    searchString = line.strip(strings)
    print("Found String %s" % searchString)
```

Comment: What is that `strings` object, beautiful?

Comment: I think this is a great problem for Regex! Are you familiar with that?

Comment: That's not a string. That's a dictionary.

Comment: @khajvah the line might have `strings` value or it might not, if it does, i want to print the exact one of the `strings` which is in the line, otherwise, no Strings found. 
@KivakWolf Not really
@tommy.carstensen I'm confused !

Comment: @MarieAnne `for i in strings:     if i in line:  print('Whatever you want to print')`

Comment: And make a list instead of dictionary.

Comment: @MarieAnne, if you are trying to search text in *HTML* formatted strings, you'd better off use a HTML processing tool like [**lxml**](http://lxml.de/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
if any(string in strings for string in line):
```

try:

```
if any(string in strings for string in line.values()):
```

That way, you're searching through the values in the `line` dictionary (e.g. `5`) instead of searching through the keys (e.g. `"pagesize"`).

Also, Python's Boolean true is `True`, not `true`.

Comment: the `true` is part of the page, not in a code or anything, I guess it's a value of a JSON

Comment: Leave it as is, then.

Answer (score 0):

Your `line` appears to be a dictionary, but you've got `true` there, which makes me think it's JSON?  Or do you mean `True`, the Python Boolean value?  I'm going to assume the latter (this is a Python dictionary, and you meant True).  Very briefly, a dictionary is an unordered collection of key/value pairs.  If I wanted the value associated with `"results_html"`, I would use `line['results_html']` to get it.  I am also going to assume you're interested in looking at the `"results_html"` key, since that's the only one that looks relevant.

Some might suggest regular expressions, but for your purposes I think that's like boiling water with an orbital laser - overkill.

You have some collection of strings and you want to find out if any of those strings appear in the dictionary.  That can be accomplished simply with this:

```
for string in strings:
    if string in line.get('results_html', ''):
        print(string)
```

I'm using the `get` method here to avoid a `KeyError` if the dictionary happens to not have a `'results_html'` key.  You could also condense it to a comprehension:

```
result = [string for string in strings if string in line.get('results_html', '')
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: lol "like boiling water with an orbital laser - overkill." I'm looking for `%E2%98%85%20Karambit%20%7C%20Boreal%20Forest%20%28Factory%20New%29` or `%E2%98%85%20Karambit%20%7C%20Safari%20Mesh%20%28Factory%20New%29` in the 'results_html' you specified, I just want to write it in a simple way, easy to understand way, so I can learn.

Comment: Then you have a few options.  Marlon Dyck's answer above will give you a solid way to search for variations.  The code I posted is more specific to the strings you mentioned but will print out each string that is found in `line['results_html']`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact kind of problem that the regex module was designed for. Regex allows for fast easy text pattern recognition.

```
import re

line = ""

x = re.findall('(%E2%98%85%20Karambit%20%7C%20(Safari%20Mesh|Boreal%20Forest)?%20%28Factory%20New%29)', line)

for i in x:
   print (i[0])
```

That searches for only the two cases you wanted using the regex 'or' operator '|'.

Alternatively you can use a wildcard operator and it wont discriminate on the words sandwiched within string.

```
x = re.findall('(%E2%98%85%20Karambit%20%7C%20.*?%20.*?%20%28Factory%20New%29)', line)

for i in x:
    print (i)
```

That will find both of the strings you wanted, and find others with a similar format such as:

```
%E2%98%85%20Karambit%20%7C%20European%20Arctic%20%28Factory%20New%29
```

Documentation for the regex module can be found here:

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html